# Electron screenshot is too small

Tags: javascript, electron

Hi I am using electron to take a screenshot of the entire screen and my code is working good, except the fact that the size of the screenshot being download is too small.

This is the js function that takes the screenshot on button click

renderer.js:

```
const electron = require('electron');

const desktopCapturer = electron.desktopCapturer;
const electronScreen = electron.screen;
const shell = electron.shell;

const remote = electron.remote;
const dialog = remote.dialog;

const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');

const screenshot = document.getElementById('screen-shot');
const screenshotMsg = document.getElementById('screenshot-path');
const pathButton = document.getElementById('path-button');

 var screenShotPath ='';

 pathButton.addEventListener('click',function (event) {
     dialog.showSaveDialog(function (fileName) {
         if(fileName == undefined){
             return;
         }
         screenShotPath = fileName;
         screenshotMsg.textContent = screenShotPath;
     });
 });
screenshot.addEventListener('click',function(event){
    screenshotMsg.textContent =  'Gathering screens';
    const thumbSize = determineScreenshot();
    console.log(thumbSize.height);
    console.log(thumbSize.width);
    let options ={types: ['screen'], thumnailSize: thumbSize};

    desktopCapturer.getSources(options,function (error,sources) {
        console.log(sources);
        if(error) return console.log(error.message);

        sources.forEach(function (source) {
           if(source.name === "Entire screen" || source.name === "Screen 1" ){
                if(screenShotPath === ''){
                    screenShotPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(),'screenshot.jpeg');
                }
                console.log(screenShotPath);
                fs.writeFile(screenShotPath,source.thumbnail.toPNG(), function (err) {
                    if(err) return console.log(err.message);

                    shell.openExternal("file://"+screenShotPath);
                    var message = 'Saved SS to ' + screenShotPath;
                    screenshotMsg.textContent = message;
                });
           }
        });
    });
});

function  determineScreenshot() {
        const screensize =electronScreen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;
        const maxDimension = Math.max(screensize.width,screensize.height);
        console.log(maxDimension);

        return {
            width: maxDimension * window.devicePixelRatio,
            height: maxDimension * window.devicePixelRatio
        };
}
```

The screenshot is capturing the work area well but the problem is it is too small. Can someone please tell how to increase the size of it? I am attaching the generated screenshot herewith.[image]

Comment: will this tutorial help? https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/280/creating-screenshots-of-your-app-or-the-screen-in-electron-framework  - BTW, you might want to double-check the numbers returned by `determineScreenshot()` - as this seems to be driving the dimensions of your screenshot.  Specially, this line: `maxDimension * window.devicePixelRatio` (and the next one)

Comment: The returned values are 1366 and 1366 but still it seems to be small

Comment: do you get any errors shown in console?

Comment: Got it, there was a error with the spelling of 'thumnailSize'

Comment: was it showing in the console? - glad it got resolved...

Comment: No i went through the code

Answer (score 1):

This might help you.

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => { // The button which takes the screenshot
    desktopCapturer.getSources({ 
        types: ['screen'],
        thumbnailSize: {
            width: 384,
            height: 216
        } 
    }).then( sources => {
        
    }) })
```